# Why is my .htaccess not working?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple htaccess with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*) /index.php?package=base&page=$1 [L]
```

It should match the following URL:

```
http://apretaste.loc/developers
```

And rewrite it like this:

```
http://apretaste.loc/index.php?package=base&page=developers
```

Everything seems to be well written, but the .htaccess is rewriting to

```
http://apretaste.loc/index.php?package=base&page=index.php
```

I have been several days on this error already... What I am doing wrong? Also, I checked the htaccess using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and seems to be rewriting correctly. I tested it on three different servers... can you see something suspicious?

Answer (score 0):

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ shows that

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*) /index.php?package=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Will rewrite

```
http://apretaste.loc/base/developers
```

To

```
http://apretaste.loc/index.php?package=base&page=developers
```

Or, to answer the original question, so will:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/(.*)$ /index.php?package=base&page=$1 [L]
```